# `THIndexTensor_(size)(target, 0) == batch_size' failed. at d:\projects\pytorch\torch\lib\thnn\generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:54

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train my neural networks on dog breeds data set. After feed-forward, during the loss computation it throws this error :

```
RuntimeError: Assertion `THIndexTensor_(size)(target, 0) == batch_size' failed.  at d:\projects\pytorch\torch\lib\thnn\generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:54
```

Code:

```
criterion =nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer=optim.Adam(net.parameters(),lr=0.001)


for epoch in range(10):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        print(len(trainloader))
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs
            inputs, labels  = data

            # wrap them in Variable
            inputs, labels = Variable(inputs).float(), Variable(labels).float().type(torch.LongTensor)


            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = net(inputs)

            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.data[0]
            if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Error is generated in this line :

```
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
```

What's the issue ??

Comment: can you print the shape of `outputs` and `labels`? use `print(outputs.size(), labels.size())` before `loss = criterion(outputs, labels)`. then we will be able to help.

Comment: here is the result of "print(outputs.size(), labels.size())"

torch.Size([2500, 120]) torch.Size([4])

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is that you are missing the batch dimension on the tensor `labels`. The error says that the size of the `0th` dimension is not equal to the batch size.

Try changing this:

```
loss = criterion(outputs, labels.unsqueeze(0))
```

Please note, the `outputs` tensor should have one more dimension than the `labels` tensor corresponding to a score for each label and the `labels` should just contain the index of the correct label.